# What is Cyua singing at the beginning of "AL℃-@"?

Tags: music, aldnoah-zero

At the beginning of "AL℃-@" (track 09 on the Aldnoah.Zero soundtrack), before the German lyrics ("Ich reich dir meine Hand" and so forth) kick in around 0:46, the vocalist (Cyua) is singing something. Whatever it is, it's not part of the printed lyrics, and it contains the word "Aldnoah". Beyond that, I'm not sure what she's singing.

I doubt that there are any official lyrics for that part of the track, but perhaps someone who has learned how to parse Hiroyuki Sawano's mangled German could weigh in?

Here is a short extract of the segment in question: http://clyp.it/h3hfpevb

Answer (score 2):

This is only vaguely an answer to my question, but: [the second OST](http://vgmdb.net/album/50322) included the piece "Harmonious" (also used as the ED for episode 23), which is a vocal piece to roughly the same melody as "AL℃-@" (this is a standard Sawano trick, as with "MKAlieZ" vs. "aLIEz"; "アZ-Kat" vs. "A/Z"; and so forth). Like "AL℃-@", it has [a 16-bar vocal introduction from 0:19 to 0:35](https://clyp.it/22xlf40w) (albeit in 3/4 rather than 4/4), but with actual comprehensible lyrics:

> 煌めく欠片
>   降り注ぐ空に
>   未来繋ぐドア
>   隠した

Roughly,

> The shining fragments, falling through the sky, concealed the door to the future.

Now, this clearly *isn't* what Cyua is singing in AL℃-@, but as [mivilar  noticed in the comments on Cole's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/what-is-cyua-singing-at-the-beginning-of-al%E2%84%83/18413#comment26814_18413), Cyua distinctly appears to be singing the word 未来 *mirai* "future", and it lines up with what the singer (Amamiya Sora / Asseylum) is singing in the third four-bar segment of the introduction to "Harmonious". Unfortunately, I have difficulty identifying any other correspondences between the known lyrics in the introduction to "Harmonious" and the unknown lyrics in the introduction to "AL℃-@".

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like "Mirai Dorama, Aldnoah" vocally stylized as "Mi-Rai Du-Ra-Ma, Ald-No-Ah", Or, "Meer-Haii Doo-Rah-Mah, Aald-Noh-Ahh".

Or, in English, maybe something like: "Future Drama Aldnoah".